# Cannot write file to sd card on android kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, sd-card, android-sdcard

My tablet samsung galaxy tab 3 10.1 Kitkat cannot write (create folder/copy data) to sd card. 
I was root the tablet, and use app like, nextapp sd fix, kitkat sd card full access in xposed installer and finally change permission acces manually, but still not working. any idea to fix that?

Comment: did you added permission.

Answer (score 3):

According to google, from Kitkat onwards it is not giving the permission to the application to write on the SDcard except from its package folder. That means, if you want to write something on SDcard with kitkat version, then create a folder structure like below on SDcard:

*/Android/data/**your.package.name**/files/**yourFiles***

After which you can read as well as write inside this folder.But for the sake of caution please keep in mind that android will delete these folder after you uninstall or clear the data of your application

Comment: Will the data also be removed, if an app is updated from Google Play ?